# MySQL utf8 multibyte (utf8mb4) insert duplicate entry problem

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates, utf8mb4

I have two words ('**বাঁধা**' and '**বাধা**') to be inserted in a mysql (8.0.12 - MySQL Community Server - GPL) table. The word 'বাঁধা' is inserted correctly. But when inserting 'বাধা', mysql produces an error:

```
INSERT INTO lc6_words(jp_word, jp_fcharascii) VALUES('বাঁধা', 2476);
/*Query OK*/
INSERT INTO lc6_words(jp_word, jp_fcharascii) VALUES('বাধা', 2476);
/*#1062 - Duplicate entry 'বাধা' for key 'jp_word'*/
```

The table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lc6_words` (
  `jp_wkey` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `jp_word` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `jp_fcharascii` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `jp_word_occ` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
UNIQUE(`jp_word`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`jp_wkey`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8MB4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

Relevant queries and their output:

```
SELECT jp_wkey FROM lc6_words WHERE BINARY jp_word='বাঁধা';
/* 1 */
SELECT jp_wkey FROM lc6_words WHERE BINARY jp_word='বাধা';
/* Empty */
```

Thanks for reading this far. And some more too if you share your thoughts :).

Comment: Try this: `select jp_word from lc6_words where jp_wkey = 0;`. You have a row where the primary key is 0, which is unusual when you have an auto-increment column.

Comment: Sorry... a mistake. There is no 0 key. Have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be problem in collation. After running the command below, all worked perfectly:

```
ALTER TABLE lc6_words MODIFY jp_word VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

**Note:** The VARCHAR size changed from 255 to 191.